# NHibernate select from more then one table

Tags: .net, sql, nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

How to write this select using NHibernate objects?

```
Select a.Id, a.Name, b.Data 
From Table1 a, Table2 b
Where a.Id between :1 and :2
And :3 = b.Period(+)
And 1 = b.Type(+)
And a.Id = b.Table1Id(+)
Order by 1
```

I.e. it gives all Table1 rows with Table2.Data for each row, even if there is no Table2 data for it (then 0 or null will be given)

Classes and mappings for Table1 and Table2 already created, and works. Reference for b.Table1Id added also.

So the problem is in (+) operator mainly.

Mappings:
Table1 is very simple and doesn't referenced to any tables. 
Table2:

```
Table("Table2");
CompositeId()
 .KeyProperty(x => x.Type)
 .KeyProperty(x => x.Table1Id)
 .KeyProperty(x => x.Period);
Map(x => x.Type);
Map(x => x.Table1Id);
Map(x => x.Period);
Map(x => x.Data);
ReferencesAny(x => x.TableG)
 .IdentityType<string>()
 .EntityTypeColumn("Type")
 .EntityIdentifierColumn("Table1Id")
 .AddMetaValue<Table1>("1")
 .AddMetaValue<Table33>("33");
```

Table1 and Table33 ingerites from one parent class TableG. Sql query updated now accordingly.

Comment: can you show the mappings as well? and what have you tried to get this query to run in nhibernate?

Comment: Mappings added. And I didn't tried to do this at all, I don't know what to start with.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this to get the records. And use projections to select the fields you want.
There is a similar example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6034725/queryover-with-select-and-orderby-in-nhibernate) to get you started.

```
var queryResult = Session.QueryOver<Table2>()
                    .Left.JoinAlias(table2 => x.Period, () => period)
                    .Where(table2 => table2.Id >= value1)
                    .Where(table2 => table2.Id <= value2)
                    .Where(table2 => table2.Type == 1)
                    .OrderBy(table2 => table2.Type).List<Table2>();
```